# CSS Overflow Property Not working

Tags: css

I'm new to `css`, the code I am using for the `overflow` property doesn't appear to be working:

```
div.hidden {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hide;
}
```

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: you made a syntax error, its hidden not hide.

Comment: Just curious to know how this thread attracted so many upvotes and favorites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

```
overflow: hidden;
```

The possible values

```
 hidden // not scroll, invisible content
 visible // not scroll, visible content
 scroll // scroll ever
 auto // scroll only if it's neccesary
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Easy mistake, keep it up you'll get it!

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
 div.hidden {
            background-color: #00FF00;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
```